# Unity: Enemy objects passing through box collider on edges of background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a simple 2D Unity game (which I'm very new to so sorry if this is a silly question!) in which my player can eat its enemies by colliding with them. This works fine as I'm just selecting the "is trigger" component for the enemies and using this code in my Player class:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit detected");
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
```

However, this means the colliders placed around the border of my background image aren't stopping the enemies. What's the best fix for this?

Comment: What is the issue with using not just Is Trigger and using collision stuff, not trigger one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your question. However it seems that your collisions are not working. So, remember that for have collisions actually taking place in your game you need to use colliders and that one of the two elements participating in the collision need to have the rigidbody component.

That will make the physics work in the engine, which triggers dont.
To check if that works you can debug with:

```
// called on collision
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
 {
      Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter2D");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want only to detect triggers between the player and the enemies, but you still want these to collide with physic objects in your scene, such as background colliders.

One possible way to achieve this is to create a child object for the player object with a collider component with the trigger option set, and attaching a script to it to handle the triggers. Then, with the use of layers to group your player and enemy objects, you can uncheck the collision between them following: Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics 2D: "Layer Collision Matrix".

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a script to any enemy, checking the distance with the player in each frame. Then you can Uncheck "is trigger"

[Vector2.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html)